# How to load menu labels from database in Yii framework using YiiBootstrap?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

Current code:

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu', array(
    'type'=>'tabs', // '', 'tabs', 'pills' (or 'list')
    'stacked'=>true, // whether this is a stacked menu
    'items'=>array(
        array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>'#', 'active'=>true),
        array('label'=>'Profile', 'url'=>'#'),
        array('label'=>'Messages', 'url'=>'#'),
    ),
)); ?>
```

If I want to fetch labels from database table then how could it be done?

Answer (score 1):

From the controller you can send the data to the view.
Then use it in the view to display.

**CONTROLLER**

```
function actionFoo() {
    //get the dynamic data
    $this->render("view_name", array('data'=>$data));
}
```

in the view you can get the data in $data. Hope its useful....

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare the labels, url and Active states in your controller

Prepare menu array as below:

```
$tems = array(
              array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>'#', 'active'=>false),
              array('label'=>'Profile', 'url'=>'#', 'active'=>false),
              array('label'=>'Messages', 'url'=>'#', 'active'=>false),
              array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>'#', 'active'=>false),             
             );
```

Pass the array to view file

```
$this->render("view_name", array('items'=>$items));
```

In View file, change widget line code to

```
'items'=> $items,
```

Comment: i want to fetch labels and urls from tables of database guys. not static

Comment: then get data from db and assign it to labels and URLS.

Comment: i know that but how to do that?